# Excel Web Access Web Part won't load any workbook

Tags: web-part, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, office-web-apps, excel-web-access-webpart

I've been attempting to troubleshoot an issue on my SharePoint 2016 site with the Excel Web Access. I'm trying to embed a simple work sheet into a page. I should simply be able to open the Web Part menu, and select the workbook, as seen in this screenshot: 
[image]

However, nothing happens once I select OK or Apply. The page simply refreshes and nothing happens. I am able to open any workbooks in the Excel Web App by clicking on them in the document library, as expected: 
[image]

I've already attempted to reload the Office Online server in to Sharepoint, which made no difference in the issue.

This was not a problem in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Hi, I was able to implement a workaround by rendering the Excel Web Access page as an iframe web part, which works fairly well, but I would still love to know where I can look to resolve the reason why I can't get the Excel Web Access web part to load any type of spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Julian Harris,

To me, it looks like Excel Service issue which is discontinued from SharePoint 2016 and added to Office Online Server.

Use below command to Set the ExcelBI  Server and it should be your SQL Server Name.

New-OfficeWebAppsExcelBIServer –ServerId DBServerName

I have tested the same feature on my Hosted SharePoint 2016 Environment and its working without any issues.

Comment: Hi, I'm not able to follow your instructions at all. Can you please be cleared? Are you certain you understand the issue? I'm not trying to work with ExcelBI with Office Online at all, at least I don't think so.